# Set column based on another column np

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to make sure column 2 is smaller than column 1 and where it is just set to 0

```
x = np.array([[0,1],[1,0]])
x = np.where((x[1] > (x[0])), 0, x)

print(x)=>[[0,0],[1,0]]
```

Comment: `x` is a Python list; so it probably doesn't behave as you desired

Comment: What's wrong with your attempt?  Did you test it piece by piece?  As noted, `x` is a list of lists; 'columns' are not a natural concept with lists.

Comment: this is a cut down version. Will update question to reflect that it's numpy. Currently setting all other columns to 0 where < x[0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this help you:

```
arr = np.array([[0,1],[1,0]])
arr[arr[:,1] > arr[:,0], 1] = 0
print(arr)
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You started with a list (of lists), so I'll give you a list answer.

First define a simple helper function:

```
def foo(row):
    if row[1]<row[0]:
        row[1] = 0
    return row
```

And apply it to `x` row by row:

```
In [37]: x = [[0,1],[1,0]]
In [38]: [foo(row) for row in x]
Out[38]: [[0, 1], [1, 0]]
```

Comment: This is going to run too many times for this to be a good idea.

Comment: Then don't start with a list!  With a 2d array, `x[:,i]` selects a column.